# Webclient does not understand blob:http uri

Tags: c#

I am trying to download data from a blob:http link problem is the webclient complains about the url formating. `blob:http://localhost/7420f6fc-9c83-43a3-aa53-4a68ebec9518` this format is not know to webclient is there another way to download this data without using Azure calls?

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    //NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
    var model = client.DownloadData(new Uri("blob:http://localhost/7420f6fc-9c83-43a3-aa53-4a68ebec9518"));
    //Also tried
    var model = client.DownloadData("blob:http://localhost/7420f6fc-9c83-43a3-aa53-4a68ebec9518");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to download Azure blob using WebClient?

Comment: the blob was created from javascript, URL.createObjectURL(evt.target.files[i]) now im trying to access that blob from C#, preference not to use CloudBlobClient. I think i need to use XMLHttpRequest and hand it over via Json at this point. If I can get ahold of the data from the blob using WebClient or HttpClient that would be amazing.

Comment: You can use Azure Storage nuget package to download blob (if blob is secure), Otherwise, you can use HttpClient to download blob (pass valid URL). your above URL is invalid.

Comment: The blob is not in Azure, it is on the client's browser and referenced with the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL and he wants to "upload it" via a download initiated from the server. Is that right? I was also trying with HttpClient with no better results.

Comment: @BrianSeimatEvoDynamicInc sorry this has not been answered in over a year and yes you were correct, but I dumped the idea and forgot what the solution was.. I think I might have just scrapped the whole blob structure all together.